# Как вывести информацию о диске в окно tkinter с помощью текстовой метки Label

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

Мне нужно что бы в окно в tkinter выводилась информация о дисках с помощью текстовой метки Label,как такое устроить?

Answer (score 0):

Берёте информацию о дисках и выводите в лейбл, пример лейбла ниже:

```
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x50")
label1 = Label(text="My name is Billy")  # в text передаёте необходимый текст
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать так,чтоб он сам определил всю необходимую информацию(количество свободного места на диске,количество занятого,количество используемого)и вывел это в лейбл?

Comment: Конечно можно, создавайте отдельный вопрос.